# how to find the my first six text input value is zero in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to through error if the first 6 digits are zero in javascript.
I tried with this code but it is not working for

```
const value = 0000001234000444;
const str = value.toString();
if(str.substring(0,6) == "000000"){
  console.log('value is start with zero')
}
```

Comment: Because the initial value is a number, the 0s disappear. Either make it a string, or pad it to a certain length, but we'd need more details to work out which.

Comment: `const value = 0000001234000444;` will be always `1234000444` so, if you want the `0` ant left make it string at first with quotes.

Comment: You cannot do that. JS stores the *value* of the number, not the numeric literal it was created from, nor is any sort of format attached to the value.

Comment: for more info. it will not consider as,  const value = **0000001234000444**; will be always 1**234000444**. if a number starts with **0**, then its consider is **octal** literal. 
so its value become **175112484**

Comment: @Roy, correction, it'll always be  175112484 :p

Comment: Yep, is `175112484` sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leading zeros are omitted in numbers in JavaScript (and many other languages).

You have the option to use a string instead:

```
const value = '0000001234000444';
if (value.indexOf('000000') === 0)
  console.log('value starts with zero');
```

Or use `String.prototype.padStart` **if you know the desired exact length of the value**:

```
const value = 0000001234000444;
const str = value.toString().padStart(16,'0');
if (value.indexOf('000000') === 0)
  console.log('value starts with zero');
```